# CROSS_COMPILE error :arm-android-eabi-gcc: Command not found

Tags: android-ndk, makefile, cross-compiling, ubuntu-11.04

when i try this command 
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-android-eabi- uImage

it show me this error message

make: /home/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-android-eabi-gcc: Command not found

and when show the files in bin directory found that 
arm-android-eabi-gcc -> not found
but  arm-eabi-gcc -> found

how can i solve this problem
and thanks

Comment: You should try: make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- uImage

Comment: thanks it's worked but finally i get this error (arm-eabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory)